# Raid is not captured when rocky8 is installed on hp 10th generation server

Tags: raid, hp

Hello? I am currently working with a ProLiant DL20 Gen10 server.

In spite of doing the following, there was a problem that Raid was not normally caught when installing Rocky 8.

1. Raid-1 two 1TB HDDs via Smart Storage Administrator
2. System Configuration -> BIOS/Platform Configuration -> Storage Options -> SATA Controller Options -> Smart Array SW RAID Support
3. Try downloading and installing the 8.7 image through the official website, not the existing Rocky 8.6 image.

Despite the following actions, during installation, each 1TB HDD is recognized separately, rather than one storage group bound by RAID.

In this case, I wonder which part should be checked.

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Is there already data on those drives in the proliant's HW raid configuration that you need access to?  If not, then you're better off with separate drives - use either linux's mdadm or zfs or btrfs, or even LVM.  Hardware RAID offers no benefit over software raid, it's just vendor lock-in...if your HW RAID card dies, you have no choice to get another identical (or at least compatible) model from the same vendor, if they still make it or if one is available on the second-hand market.  With SW raid, you can use any disk controller.

Answer (score 1):

Smart Array SW RAID is a software raid. So you need driver to see/operate it. I hardly see the way to use it out of the box with Linux.

On [HP site](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-a00026445en_us) you can read:

> A device driver is required for the Operating System (OS) to
> communicate with the disk drive controller.

Better use `md` or `LVM` to create mirroring for the partitions.